# Set labelText of input with Bootstrap Switch

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

### Description:

I went through Bootstrap Switch's [documentation](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/options.html) but it's not very clear how I'm supposed to change the labelText of the switch input.

```
Name      | Attribute      | Type  | Description                             | Values | Default
----------+----------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+--------+--------
labelText | data-label-text| String| Text of the center handle of the switch |  String| '&nbsp;'
```

Here is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: label on text]
[image: label off text]

I get that just with no text in the "Label" area.

### What I've tried:

I can set the labelText by default this way:

```
$.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.labelText = 'Label!';
```

but I'm not looking to set every single bootstrapSwitch labelText to "Label!" just one.

I tried $`("#my-input").labelText("Label!");` 
but that didn't work (didn't expect it to)

### Question:

How do I set the label text for one input with Bootstrap Switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML - Just change the value of "data-label-text" attribute.

```
<input id="my-input" type="checkbox" data-label-text="Label!">
```

OR

In JQuery

```
$("#my-input").siblings(".bootstrap-switch-label").text("Label!");
```

Answer (score 2):

In Jquery I use:

```
$('#my-input').bootstrapSwitch('labelText', 'Label!');
```